# I'm hitting my front with my back

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Here're some facts about me:

```
I'm green.  
I'm brown.  
I cannot be eaten.  
I'm yummy.  
I'm hot.  
I'm cold.  
I'm hitting my front with my back.
```

What am I?
(EDIT: Hint 3)

hint 1:

> wordplay tag added

hint 2:

> you'll probably see me in a refrigerator, on a stage or on a plate

hint 3:

> I'm referring to 4 things that shares the same name, 1 being musical and 3 edible!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a longshot, but my guess is:

> Drumstick (musical drumstick, chicken drumstick, drumstick tree, ice cream treat drumstick)

I'm green.

> There is a plant called a "[Drumstick Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moringa_oleifera)" that is quite green.

I'm brown.

> The skin of a chicken drumstick, a musical drumstick, the ice cream treat, and the bark of the drumstick tree are all brown.

I cannot be eaten.

> A drumstick for music is not edible. Many parts of the drumstick tree don't have culinary uses.

I'm yummy.

> A chicken drumstick is definitely yummy though, as is the ice cream treat. Also, the fruit, seeds, and leaves of the drumstick tree have culinary uses.

I'm hot.

> Chicken drumsticks are served hot and so are the fruit and seeds of the drumstick tree.

I'm cold.

> Drumstick tree leaves are served cold on salads. The ice cream treat is definitely cold.

I'm hitting my front with my back.

> You hit a drum ("front" of the word) with a stick ("back" of the word)!

Hint 2 & 3

> Hint 2: The fruit, leaves, and seeds of the drumstick tree are refrigerated and the ice cream treat is frozen. A musical drumstick is used on stage. A chicken drumstick is often served on plate. Hint 3: There is one musical use for drumstick (drums), and three for edible (chicken, drumstick tree, ice cream treat).

Comment: This actually looks pretty plausible!

Comment: andddddd we've a winner!

Answer (score 20):

> Tea!!

I'm green.

> Green tea is a very popular style.

I'm brown.

> Many herbal teas have a brownish color after steeping.

I cannot be eaten.

> But you can be drunk!

I'm yummy.

> Many people love the taste of tea.

I'm hot.
I'm cold.

> Hot tea and iced tea are both acceptable.

I'm hitting my front with my back.

> The front of "tea" is the letter "t". When you add the back - the "ea", the word "tea" is pronounced the same as the letter "t". So "with the back" the word hits the front. (This one's a stretch.)

Comment: I think this is right but not sure about the last one

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about the last one either, but thanks for the vote of confidence!

Comment: This is not the answer but you're going the right direction, esp the way how you come up with the last line.

Comment: @Alex maybe the wordplay tag is appropriate then?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I was thinking to add it but was afraid to make it too obvious, guess i will add it

Answer (score 4):

> An acorn?

I'm green.

> When unripe

I'm brown.

> When ripe

I cannot be eaten.

> Because of the hard shell

I'm yummy.

> The inside of acorns are actually very nice

I'm hot.
I'm cold.

> From [this](http://www.downanddirtygardening.com/2010/11/acorns-two-ways.html) website...
> -hot leaching acorns is fast (relatively) and easy
> -hot leached acorns aren't appropriate for flour as they won't bind to form a dough once the nuts have been heated at more than 150 F
> -hot leached acorns may still produce a dark liquid even after being leached of all bitterness, so rely on your taste buds rather than the color of the leaching water
> -cold leaching acorns is slow and more labor intensive
> -cold leached acorns make a flour that will bind in a bread dough but should still not be used 100% in place of wheat flours; it contains no gluten and will not rise

I'm hitting my front with my back.

> Not sure, something to do with the cap?

Comment: Not the correct answer but good guess!

Answer (score 1):

This should satisfy all the criteria even if I'm not fully convinced ...

> Pepper

I'm green.

> Green peppers are pretty green.

I'm brown.

> Peppercorns? Also the unreleased, but leaked single by the Red Hot Chili Peppers

I cannot be eaten.

> Please don't eat the musicians ...

I'm yummy.

> Green peppers are indeed tasty.

I'm hot.

> Spicy or cooked, take your pick. Or in the name of the band.

I'm cold.

> Peppers can be refrigerated. There was also a song by RHCP called "Stone Cold Bush"

I'm hitting my front with my back.

> The second syllable of "pepper" starts with the letter P, as does the word itself. This is the party about which I'm unsure.

Hint 2 (and 3):

> Refrigerator: green pepper, Stage: Red Hot Chili Peppers, Plate: Peppercorn, ground pepper, etc. 3 things that share the same name, 1 musical and 2 edible.

Comment: Would've been an alternative answer if the last one fit.  Not the answer buy very good guess!